# Split datatable to many small datatables Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a big table like this :

[image]

the my goal is to create n tables like this :

[image]

and second one when teno =1 and ex=2 ect ect

with name of that table equals something like = 1_0.5 then second table 1_2 ect ect ...

what is the most efficient way to this in python ?

Comment: You want to create n dataframes of size 2 x all columns?

Comment: Yes with all columns size in my real table isn't 2, it's changing can't be fixed ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I think something like this will work for you:

```py
import pandas as pd
# I don't know where you have your data stored but you'll use some kind of pandas
# read method to load that data into a dataframe (which i'll call df)
df = pd.read_csv("./your-data.csv")
# get a list of each set of unique filters you'll use to create your smaller dataframes
filters = df[['teno', 'ex']].drop_duplicates().values.tolist()
# loop through filter sets
tables = dict()
for filter in filters:
    # pull out teno and ex filters. (teno will be in the first position, ex 
    # in the second)
    teno_filter = filter[0]
    ex_filter = filter[1]
    # filter df, append to list of smaller dfs
    filtered_df = df[(df['teno'] == teno_filter) & (df['ex'] == ex_filter)]
    tables[str(teno_filter) + "_" + str(ex_filter)] = filtered_df

# you can then access each filtered table by selecting from the `tables` dictionary
# for example, to access your first table:
first_table = tables["1_0.5"]
```

I think you'll find that storing all of the tables in a single dictionary will work better than creating a bunch of tables named like 1_0.5, etc. This way they are all stored together, can be accessed in a loop, and you can still work with them individually if you'd like

Comment: It works thank you, is there a way instead of a list use table ?

Comment: Which list do you want to replace with a table? `filters`?

Comment: small_dfs i was more thinking about creating tables for each filtre

Comment: Sure you'd just need to come up with a naming scheme so you can assign each filtered table a variable name rather than just storing it in `small_dfs`. If you know how you'd like each table named (name of the first table, name of the second table, etc) lmk and I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: I was actually thinking to put find a scheme to name automatically each table with name linked to filters for example first table name will be something like this : 1_0.5 then second table 1_2 ect ect ...

Comment: I think the best way to do this would be with a python dictionary. I'll update my example to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you the solution is perfect just can't access tables["1_0.5"] i get a keyerror is that normal ?